# Are there binary way to convert integer hundred position to zero?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a function `HundredPosToZero` to convert hundred position to zero, for example :

```
HundredPosToZero(4239) // 4039
```

This is my implement :

```
public HundredPosToZero(int num){
  return num / 1000 * 1000 + num % 100;
}
```

However, I'm thinking of why not use `bitwise operator` like `4239 & 1011` to do the same thing? But I can not figure out how to implement it since 4239 is not a binary, any advice with this approach?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work since `4039/1000 == 4` + `39` = `43`.

Comment: Thanks guys that's my mistake, I have edited my solution

Comment: You can't do it via bitwise operations. Note that 100d = 1100100b and 200d = 11001000b. Notice that different bits are set. So removing 100 from a number and removing 200 from a number acts differently at a binary level.

Comment: IMO, any attempt to do this with binary operators will increase complexity and number of operations needed to perform this. I suggest keeping it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. There is nothing special about decimal hundreds in binary. It would be possible with e.g. a hexadecimal number, but decimal numbers don't play well with binary :)

Answer (score 1):

It is simply impossible if you want this operation to be the same for all numbers as "hundreds" in regular representation of integers don't occupy the same set of bits.

If you use some other binary representation of numbers (like [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)) that allocates groups of bits to unique decimal digits then you can do that easily.